# Sprinkler System - Winterization planning ahead

Tags: sprinkler-system

**Introduction**

I am installing a new sprinkler system and this is my first time. I have done a lot of research including reading the plumbing code and what is required. I see that I need a pressure vacuum breaker which is no problem. I have purchased this [one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KI0WORE) as it is recommended all over the place. I am definitely proficient in plumbing and have done many new installs and repairs. The sprinkler part is what is new to me.

**My setup**

[image]

**Question**

So before I go installing things, I was just trying to plan everything out. In the winter of course I will need to drain the water out of the lines. As I understand it, the pressure vacuum valve acts as a one way valve to not allow water to flow backwards. If this is true, then how does one design the system so it can be fully drained? Since it is recommended to place it 12 inches above the highest point of the sprinkler heads, water would never flow backwards to the drain, and even if you drain it from the PVB itself, it is higher than the system, so how does the water flow up?

The inlet water source comes from a basement so I can definitely get lower than the sprinkler heads, but won't the PVB block it from that direction?

Comment: If I understand them, they only break the vacuum, so if you chop the inlet with an axe, the vacuum created will not pull the outside water in.  They might prevent a lower drain from working to to drain the higher lines.

Comment: Ah so the water can still flow backwards? Then my lower drain valve would still work since lower than entire system. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "drain" the underground pipes you would need them to be laid out with a strategy similar to the indoor DWV plumbing, with intentional slope everywhere leading to a drain point.   Unless you live on a mountainside this would be difficult.  Instead, what you do before winter is blow out the pipes with compressed air.

The section from the house to the vacuum breaker can be "drained" if it's installed intentionally to make that possible.  Your diagram is probably just a diagram but if it were really configured that way  it would probably drain fine.

On the outside, you put some valves just after the vacuum breaker and a connection point for an air compressor.  When it does come time to blow out the sprinklers, you need to hire a landscaper with a very large compressor -- the kind that gets towed behind a heavy truck.  You can't do it with any residential or shop one because you need a high volume of air.

You should get a book and/or watch some  youtube videos of end-to-end installations so you don't miss steps.  And go look at some neighbors' installations done by professionals.  It's not hard if you have plumbing experience, and mistakes are not costly so it's a good learning project but if you're unaware of key components it'll take you a long time to get it right!

Comment: Thank you as this is very helpful.  I read that using air to blow it out is considered dangerous or can wreck your system by some people.  Would you think this not to be true? I think as long as the system isn't a vacuum it wouldn't be an issue too

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do it.  Everyone I know has their system blown out in fall by a landscaper.  I suppose it has its dangers, yes .... they use an enormous compressor that probably requires some training and safety procedures, and I don't know what those are ... because they charge $75 and even to rent a suitable compressor for one day would cost more than that.  Could it damage your system?  Probably, if you don't know what you're doing but I guess you learn ..... [ 1/ 2 ]

Comment: [2 / 2] .... but, off topic for this question I may as well tell you now .... what causes the most damage on a regular basis to my sprinkler system is the plug aerator.   Because my system hoses were laid too shallow.   So ...... "don't do that" .... bury them at the correct depth and if you aerate your lawn, expect occasional damage to heads and funny pipes.   Next worst offender ... if you don't have a curb (lawn abuts road) keep sprinkler heads at least 2 feet away from the road.  People WILL drive on them, snowplows will occasionally encroach, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Blowing it out with moderate pressure (say 30-40 PSI) is perfectly safe. I do it every year and have never had a problem.  You'll need a pressure regulator and an inlet port for the compressed air.   The more advanced, larger sprinkler system controllers have a "test pattern" that will open each zone for a user specified time. I think the default on my RainBird controller is 2 minutes, but it can be changed if needed.

It makes it pretty easy to prep for winter: Just connect the compressor **WITH A PRESSURE REGULATOR SET TO ABOUT 30 PSI  OR SO** .   It takes a decent sized compressor to get the job done.  Those little "pancake" compressors, like the kind used for trim nailers are just too small.

A couple pieces of advice as you design your system.  Be sure you install a double check valve to make it code legal.  Next:  Make sure you have "head to head coverage"    It sounds counterintuitive, but believe me, you'll glad you did.  You didn't mention if you were on a well or municipal water supply but be sure you don't make your zones so large that the well or muni water can't adequately supply them. RainBird has some pretty decent planning instructions.

Comment: How big is your compressor?  (Volume capacity, weight).  Is my answer wrong, where I say you need a tow-behind-sized machine?   How big are your zones?  Mine are up to 4 heads with maybe 90 feet of 1 inch pipe to the last head.

Comment: @jay613  It's a 50 gallon 3 hp compressor and it can barely keep up with the blow out of the zones.  But in my case most zones have 8-12 heads , so it takes a lot of compressed air. BTW,   I didn't take issue with your answer and didn't DV it.